# Use map object in karate framework

Tags: kotlin, karate, system-testing

I am trying to create a scenario where:

```
  Scenario Outline: Create a request
    Given print 'reason=<reason>, detail=<detail>, metainfo=<metainfo>'
    When call create_request
    Then match response.message == "#notnull"

    * call json_to_proto request
    * print 'response \n', response

    Examples:
      reason     | detail  | metainfo
      test       | Testing | { foo: bar }
```

My concern is metainfo is defined as a map, "metainfo": "#(karate.get('metainfo', {}))" how do I set values for it as the current logic gives me error: org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: Expect a map object but found...

Answer (score 0):

Please read this section of the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#scenario-outline-enhancements

You can use JSON like this. And note that you don't need the `<foo>` placeholder system. Normal variables work:

```
Scenario Outline: ${payload.foo}
  * match payload == { foo: 'bar' }

  Examples:
    | payload!       |
    | { foo: 'bar' } |
```

Comment: I am new to this, can you please help elaborate the example, am I supposed to set the values as: ```  Scenario Outline: Create a request
    Given print 'reason=<reason>, detail=<detail>, metainfo=<metainfo>'
    When call create_request
    Then match response.message == "#notnull"

    * call json_to_proto request
    * print 'response \n', response

    Examples:
      reason     | detail  | metainfo!
      test       | Testing | { "foo": "bar" }````